# AG Grid's icons are not getting included in the build

Tags: javascript, laravel, svelte, vite, inertiajs

I have `"ag-grid-community": "^30.0.6"` installed. I'm including default styles, that are used in ag grid's demo.

```
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
```

While running `npm run dev` everything works fine, icons are present and inspected filter element with icon looks like this copying the element from the inspector:

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="ag-button ag-floating-filter-button-button"
    ref="eButtonShowMainFilter"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-label="Open Filter Menu"
>
    <span
        class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter"
        unselectable="on"
        role="presentation"
    >
        ::before
    </span>
</button>
```

Project is using Laravel - Inertiajs - Svelte and the js is bundled using Vite.

When `npm run build` finishes, the buttons are still present, however the `::before` part is missing and the icons are not displayed.

How to include the icons in the build?